# Como usar o flag /authuser da função imap_open() do PHP?

Tags: php

```
imap_open("{".HOST.":143/authuser=teste@teste.memphis.com.br/novalidate-cert}INBOX", $email , $pass);
```

A linha acima é ilustrativa, busco aqui uma ajudar para usar esses parametros corretamente.

Vou explicar oque preciso fazer.

Preciso acessar o mailbox do zimbra, acessar um usuario de cada vez e mover os emails da pasta SPAM para outra.
O meu problema esta como fazer essa conexão a cada conta, pelo que vi a função imap do php não seleciona contas em massa para essa tarefa.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Como não tive respostas, buscando uma solução incansavelmente encontrei. A sintaxe correta para acessar as sub-contas por meio do admin do zimbra:

- user=teste // usuario ao que ser quer acesso
- authuser=admin // administrador zimbra
- $email  // email do administrador zimbra
- $pass  // password do administrador zimbra

imap_open("{".HOST.":143/user=teste@domain.com.br/authuser=admin/novalidate-cert}INBOX",    $email , $pass);

Desa maneira consigo ter acesso a qualquer mailbox cadastrado no zimbra e fazer as alterações necessárias.